# Why did I get the ""exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" when I use cursor already?

Tags: plsql, triggers, cursor

I am using the cursor to write the following codes, so that the cursor can pick up multiple lines. However, it still gives me the error message "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". Isn't that the cursor will retrieve data one line at a time. Why is this message still showing?

```
 create or replace trigger e
    before delete on enrollment
    for each row
    declare 
       get_tid scorest.tid%type;
       get_ferm scorest.ferm%type;
       get_sect scorest.sect%type;
       get_name scorest.name%type;
       get_score scorest.score%type;
       cursor findenrolls(atid in scorest.tid%type, 
                          aferm in scorest.ferm%type, 
                          asect in scorest.sect%type)
                          is select * from scorest;
    begin 
       for findenrolls_rec in findenrolls(:old.tid, :old.ferm, :old.sect) loop      
          select tid, ferm, sect, name, score
          into get_tid, get_ferm, get_sect, get_name, get_score
          from scorest
          where scorest.tid=:old.tid
          and scorest.ferm=:old.ferm
          and scorest.sect=:old.sect;

      insert into deleted_scores values (get_tid, get_ferm, get_sect, get_name, get_score);

      delete from scorest
      where tid=get_tid
      and ferm=get_ferm
      and sect=get_sect
      and name=get_name;
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error come from this statement part. **select into** must return exact one record.

> ```
>     select tid, ferm, sect, name, score
>       into get_tid, get_ferm, get_sect, get_name, get_score
>       from scorest
>       where scorest.tid=:old.tid
>       and scorest.ferm=:old.ferm
>       and scorest.sect=:old.sect;
> ```

You must rewrite your code make it work. Without knowing you use case it can be harder, but you can try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER e before DELETE 
ON enrollment 
FOR EACH row 
BEGIN
    FOR get IN (
        SELECT tid
            , ferm
            , sect
            , name
            , score
            FROM scorest
            WHERE scorest.tid=:old.tid
            AND scorest.ferm =:old.ferm
            AND scorest.sect =:old.sect
    )
    LOOP
        INSERT
        INTO deleted_scores VALUES
            ( get.tid
            , get.ferm
            , get.sect
            , get.name
            , get.score
            );

        DELETE
        FROM scorest
        WHERE tid=get.tid
        AND ferm =get.ferm
        AND sect =get.sect
        AND name =get.name;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

How you can see the explicit cursor is gone and replaced by an implicit one, this look more appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 0):

error is coming due to duplicate data in scorest table based on tid , ferm ,sect
you can check this by

```
  select  tid , ferm ,sect from scorest having count(1)>1
  group by  tid , ferm ,sect;
```

if you don't need duplicates when you can put one more condition in your select statement

```
 select tid, ferm, sect, name, score
          into get_tid, get_ferm, get_sect, get_name, get_score
          from scorest
          where scorest.tid=:old.tid
          and scorest.ferm=:old.ferm
          and scorest.sect=:old.sect;
          and rownum =1
```

else you can which to approach suggested by "Ftaveras ".